# Wrapping custom symbols around your drawing in Inkscape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, 3d, symbols

In Adobe illustrator, one can create a custom symbol and then wrap it around any surface (say a face of a rectangle or a sphere). This feature is most likely under the advanced option of 3D and Bevel option of Adobe illustrator.

I have created this rectangle,and want to wrap a symbol around its outer surface. Is there a way in Inkscape to do so?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. No. Inkscape has no 3D capabilities. Maybe have a look at using Blender, a 3D modelling application which is also free and Open Source.

Comment: Your rectangle looks like a cylindrical pipe to me. :)

Comment: @userunknown Haha :) yes i meant cylinder. Thanks for pointing out.